# iOS photo gallery library?

Tags: ios, open-source, photo-gallery

I found one library two months ago and now I can't remember what was its name.
It does basically this:

[image]

I have multiple rectangles with different sizes and I want to add them in this scrollable view.

Does anyone know the name of that library?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like justified View.
Get it here:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/justified-view

https://github.com/jhsonzhi/JustifiedView

Answer (score 1):

This is pinterest-style layout, I suggest looking here:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/tags/pinterest

CocoaControls.com is the very first place for me to search for custom ios controls, I am really recommend it.